# Reading default arguments with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

When using something like this with argparse:

```
parser.add_argument("-option1", type=int, nargs=1, default=1, choices=xrange(1, 10), help="option 1 message")
```

If the argument is not passed, args.option1 is an integer. If an argument is passed, args.option is a list.

Which means I have to use either args.option1 or args.option1[0]. Is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `nargs` to an integer, the argument will always be a list when specified. You could use `'?'` instead to have it set to a single value *or* the default:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-option1", type=int, nargs='?', default=1, 
    choices=xrange(1, 10), help="option 1 message")
```

From the [`nargs` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> - `N` (an integer). `N` arguments from the command line will be gathered together **into a list.**
>
> [...]
>
> - `'?'`. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and **produced as a single item**. If no command-line argument is present, the value from default will be produced.

Emphasis mine. You *probably* want to set `const` as well though, in case someone uses *just* `-option1` on the command line with no value following it; without `const` the value is then set to `None`. Just set it to the same value as the default:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-option1", type=int, nargs='?', default=1, const=1,
    choices=xrange(1, 10), help="option 1 message")
```

Another option is to **not** set `nargs`:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "-option1", type=int, default=1, 
    choices=xrange(1, 10), help="option 1 message")
```

This usually means *almost* the same as `nargs='?'`:

> If the `nargs` keyword argument is not provided, the number of arguments consumed is determined by the action. **Generally this means a single command-line argument will be consumed and a single item (not a list) will be produced.**

with the difference being that an *empty* `-option1` argument on the command line is not permitted; no `const` needs to be set.

Demo:

```
>>> from argparse import ArgumentParser
>>> parser = ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument(
...     "-option1", type=int, nargs='?', default=1, const=1,
...     choices=xrange(1, 10), help="option 1 message")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-option1'], dest='option1', nargs='?', const=1, default=1, type=<type 'int'>, choices=xrange(1, 10), help='option 1 message', metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['-option1', '4'])  # option with argument
Namespace(option1=4)
>>> parser.parse_args(['-option1'])       # option with *no* argument
Namespace(option1=1)
>>> parser.parse_args([])                 # option not specified
Namespace(option1=1)
>>> parser = ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument(
...     "-option1", type=int, default=1, 
...     choices=xrange(1, 10), help="option 1 message")
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-option1'], dest='option1', nargs=None, const=None, default=1, type=<type 'int'>, choices=xrange(1, 10), help='option 1 message', metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['-option1', '4'])  # option with argument
Namespace(option1=4)
>>> parser.parse_args([])                 # option not specified
Namespace(option1=1)
>>> parser.parse_args(['-option1'])       # option with *no* argument
usage: [-h] [-option1 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}]
: error: argument -option1: expected one argument
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a list because you set `nargs=1` in the arguments to `add_argument`. This is also outlined in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> Note that `nargs=1` produces a list of one item. This is different from the default, in which the item is produced by itself.

If you remove `nargs=1`, it should produce the item on its own as desired (from the argument if given, otherwise from `default`). Should you want to make the number optional (i.e. also allow `-option1` without argument), use `nargs='?'` and set `const` as the default value for that case.